# Window is Not Responding?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
from pandas import *
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import tkinter.messagebox as box
ride=tk.Tk()
ride.geometry("{}x{}".format(GetSystemMetrics(0),GetSystemMetrics(1)))
frame = Frame(ride)
def ok1():
    mySQLconnection = mysql.connector.connect(user="root",passwd="1234",database="reactor1")
    cursor = mySQLconnection .cursor()
    cursor.execute("select Password from admincredentials")
    data1 = DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
    data1.rename(columns={0:'at'},inplace=True)
    s=0
    s = data1.loc[:,'at'].values
    if(s[0]==entry1.get()):
        rate=tk.Tk()
        rate.title('Change Password')
        rate.geometry("{}x{}".format(GetSystemMetrics(0),GetSystemMetrics(1)))
        frame = Frame(rate)
        def ok():
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user="root",passwd="1234",database="reactor1")
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS admincredentials")
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE admincredentials (Username varchar(20),Password varchar(20))")
            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO admincredentials (Username,Password) VALUES (%s,%s)""",('admin',entry2.get(),))
            mydb.commit()
            rate.destroy()
        Label(rate,text = 'Enter new password:',bg='white',font='Arial 10 bold').pack(padx=15,pady= 5)
        entry2 = Entry(rate,bd =5)
        entry2.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
        Button(frame,text='ok',command=ok,bg='black',fg='white').pack()
        frame.pack(padx=100,pady = 19)
        ride.destroy()
        rate.mainloop()
    else:
        box.showinfo('Info','Password does not match. Please enter the correct password')
Label1 = Label(ride,text = 'Enter old password:',bg='white',font='Arial 10 bold')  #Text(Username) to be displayed
Label1.pack(padx=15,pady= 5)
entry1 = Entry(ride,bd =5) #Entry box to enter the username
entry1.pack(padx=15, pady=5)
Button(frame,text='ok',command=ok1,bg='black',fg='white').pack()
frame.pack(padx=100,pady = 19)
ride.mainloop()
```

I want to change the password by checking the old password. It is checking the old password and opening the next window to enter new password. But after entering the new password, i am getting window is not responding. If i run only the second part(new password) separately it's working fine.

Comment: Try use `Toplevel` instead of creating another instance of `Tk`.

Comment: used toplevel but still same problem

Comment: you called `ride.destroy()` which would exit the mainloop. If you just want to hide the window, use `ride.iconify()`, and later `ride.deiconify()` to bring it back

Comment: program should have only one `mainloop` and only one main window `Tk`. Other widows create with `Toplevel`.